# Random text on page reloading

Tags: javascript

i have section for book quotes like this.
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YVjx.png)

i want to replace new quote from json file with it's own author and book name when the page is reloading.
it's my code:

```
<section class="piece_book section">
  <h3 class="piece_book--title">A Piece of Book</h3>
  <div class="piece_box">
    <p class="piece_book--text">
      “It is only with the heart that one can see rightly; what is essential
      is invisible to the eye.”
    </p>
    <div class="piece_book--info">
      <p class="piece_book--author">Antoine de Saint-Exupéry</p>
      <p class="piece_book--name">The Little Prince</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

how can do it?

Comment: To improve your question, you could display how your JSON is formatted, and see in what file it is relative to your HTML page.

Comment: Without any information on how it is implemented how are we supposed to help you? There are infinite answers for that question... You must realize it is just impossible to answer with that litle information...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if your JSON is an external file, you'll need to fetch data, therefore show a loading animation while fetching the data with Ajax:

```
async function getJSONData() {
  const data = await fetch('mydata.json');
  const result = await data.json(); // i guess it's an array of quotes
  // Chose one randomly:
  const indexOfQuote = getRandomInt(0, result.length);
  const quote = result[indexOfQuote];
  // then according to the shape of your data, you will display
  // what's need to be displayed by selecting the right elements
  // Example:
  const quoteElement = document.querySelector("#piece_book--text");
  // and inserting the content:
  quoteElement.textContent = quote.text; // for example
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

// function you can call like this:
getJSONData();
```

This in a script tag right before `</body>` in your HTML file.

More details on `fetch` on the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

### Edit

You may get some trouble with CORS policy if you're developing on a local file in your system. The option `mode: 'no-cors'` from `fetch()` does not fix the problem as we may think. It disables the warning but it doesn't disable the protections. If you have any problem with that, use `Live Server` extension on Visual Studio Code, which will create a `localhost` which seems to be a more trusted environment lol.

Answer (score 0):

What about using ajax?
You can use $.ajax() to send ajax requests if you're using `jQuery`. If you use only `javascript`, you could use XHR object to send ajax requests.
Here's the simple code using jQuery below.

```
$.ajax(
    json_url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        $('.piece_book--text').html(data.book_text);
        ...
    }
);
```

You can see more about `$.ajax` on [jQuery API Document](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

1 - Read JSON file array of objects.

```
let quotes = [{
    author: "xxx",
    quote: "xxx",
    bookName: "xxx" }]; // created from JSON or from any API
```

2 - use Math.Random and select one object from the quotes array.

```
let selectedQuote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random()*quotes.length)];
```

3 - use this selectedQuote object and bind it to your HTML, onload at body tag would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

First you need array of quotes. Then you need to select random quote from array on load.

Here is working example:

```js
var quoteArray = [
    '“Quote N 1“',
    '“Quote N 2“',
    '“Quote N 3“',
    '“Quote N 4“',
    '“Quote N 5“'
];
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * quoteArray.length);

window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  document.getElementsByClassName("piece_book--text")[0].innerHTML = quoteArray[randomNumber];
});
```

```html
<section class="piece_book section">
  <h3 class="piece_book--title">A Piece of Book</h3>
  <div class="piece_box">
    <p class="piece_book--text"></p>
    <div class="piece_book--info">
      <p class="piece_book--author">Antoine de Saint-Exupéry</p>
      <p class="piece_book--name">The Little Prince</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```